# Passing value out from reading function of firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to passing out the value which located in the reading function of firebase which is forEach loop. Yet I can't figure out why it does not work with the following code.

```
var object = {};
  var objectKey = objectKey ? objectKey : firebase.database().ref().child('test').push().key;
  object[objectKey] = {a:"1", b:"2", c:"3"};
  firebase.database().ref('test').update(object);

  var objRef = firebase.database().ref('test');
  var displayObj;
  var total = 0;
  objRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
      displayObj = childSnapshot.val();
      var a = displayObj.a;
      var b = displayObj.b;
      var c = displayObj.c;
      total = a + b + c;
      console.log(total);       //expected result: 123
      return total;
    });
  });
  console.log(total);           //I wish to set total = 123 but instead 
                                //it return the original value, 0
```

For your information, the writing function and reading function are working well as I have tested through the firebase console.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`objRef.on` is asynchronous, meaning it returns immediately before results are available to the callback function.  The callback function is executed some time later with the snapshot of the data you've asked for.

On top of that, your return value coming from `return total` is being returned from the callback function, which is meaningless.  It has no bearing on the value of the log line following the callback.

Going even further, the callback you passed to on() is going to be called repeatedly as the data at the location pointed to by `objRef` changes.  This is probably not what you want.  If you want a single snapshot at a location, use once() instead of on().

The bottom line is this: Realtime Database callbacks are asynchronous, so if you want to use a value from a snapshot coming from Realtime Database, deal with it only *after* the callback in invoked.  Please read this blog to know more about [why Firebase APIs are asynchronous](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-the-firebase-apis-asynchronous-e037a6654a93).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But still I can't get the value after changing from '.on' to '.once'. Am I using the wrong way to return the value?

Comment: It's not just changing from on to once.  Please read the entire answer - the database call is asynchronous and returns immediately, before the callback is called.